# How to filter nvarchar greater than numeric value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, query-optimization

I have a MS SQL table McTable with column BigMacs nvarchar(255). I would like to get rows with BigMacs value greater than 5.

What I do is:

```
select * from
  (
    select 
      BigMacs BigMacsS, 
      CAST(BigMacs as Binary) BigMacsB, 
      CAST(BigMacs as int) BigMacsL
    from 
      McTable
    where 
      BigMacs Like '%[0-9]%'
  ) table
where 
  Cast(table.BigMacsL as int) > 5
```

And in result I get an error:

> State 1, Line 67 Conversion failed
>   when converting the nvarchar value
>   '***' to
>   data type int.

But when I remove last filter `where Cast(table.BigMacsL as int) > 5` it works and I get this result:

```
6    0x360000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 6
23   0x320033000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 23
22   0x320032000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 22
24   0x320034000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 24
25   0x320035000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 25
3    0x330000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 3
17   0x310037000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 17
17   0x310037000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 17
19   0x310039000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 19
20   0x320030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 20
659  0x360035003900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 659
1    0x310000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1
43   0x340033000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 43
44   0x340034000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 44
45   0x340035000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 45
46   0x340036000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 46
47   0x340037000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 47
44   0x340034000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 44
44   0x340034000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 44
47   0x340037000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 47
43   0x340033000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 43
50   0x350030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 50
44   0x340034000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 44
```

And when I change in first query 'select * from' to 'select top 18 * from' than I do not get error too!

I don't know what is the problem and how to make it work! Could you please help me?

Once again: what I try to accomplish here is to get these McTable rows that have BigMacs value greater than 5.

**UPDATE**

**Steps to reproduce this error:**

I've prepared queries so You can easily get this error on your database:

Create database TestDB, create table with:

```
USE [TestDB]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TestTable]    Script Date: 04/08/2009 16:27:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MyVal] [nvarchar](255) COLLATE Polish_CI_AS NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

insert values with:

```
delete from TestDB.dbo.TestTable
insert into TestDB.dbo.TestTable (MyVal) values ('fd')
insert into TestDB.dbo.TestTable (MyVal) values ('54543534')
insert into TestDB.dbo.TestTable (MyVal) values ('fat3tv3gv5')
insert into TestDB.dbo.TestTable (MyVal) values ('fdf4v43 4v434v')
insert into TestDB.dbo.TestTable (MyVal) values (' g dfg dfg df')
insert into TestDB.dbo.TestTable (MyVal) values ('f sd 4t4gsdf')
insert into TestDB.dbo.TestTable (MyVal) values ('f df 4 trwefg')
insert into TestDB.dbo.TestTable (MyVal) values ('f sd f4  fgsfg sd')
insert into TestDB.dbo.TestTable (MyVal) values ('54534534')
insert into TestDB.dbo.TestTable (MyVal) values ('454')
```

This query:

```
    select 
        CAST(MyVal as int) MyValInt 
    from 
        dbo.TestTable 
    where 
        IsNumeric(MyVal) = 1
```

results in valid numbers as shown below:

> 54543534
>
> 54534534
>
> 454

And when you try to get filtered values with this query:

```
select 
    * 
from
    (
        select 
            CAST(MyVal as int) MyValInt 
        from 
            dbo.TestTable 
        where 
            IsNumeric(MyVal) = 1
    ) tabela
where 
    tabela.MyValInt > 6
```

You should get this error that should not occur:

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'fd' to data type int.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-in-stackoverflow

Comment: @tomaszs: I was asking for "why" not "what"...

Comment: @Sung, And there you have answer for your "Why" question

Comment: Ok, let me ask. Who set it to community wiki, and under what rationale? What is it about this question that puts it in the community wiki category? Did the person asking the question set it that way, or did someone else?

Comment: @tpdi:  It was modified only once by me. -> Added a new tag "sql".  So it looks like the question was marked as wiki from the beginning.

Comment: I've asked this question and do not want any rep from this. Please continue meta discussion about this in the link listed above.

Comment: @tomaszs: is this the entire resultset? Are you sure there's no error statement way down at the bottom of your window?

Comment: Look again at my answer. I have added an example.

Comment: @tomaszs: can you confirm if the latest query I've posted is working for you or not?

Comment: It seems to be a problem of nvarchar data type column. Lieven - your solution works for varchar, but for nvarchar not. Looks like a bug in query optimiser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

New answer for your revised scripts. What is happening is that the SQL Server query optimiser is optimising out your subquery. It is performing a single scan of the test table, and combining the inner and outer WHERE clauses into one. That's why you get the error still. To see this, view the estimated execution plan for the query, and hover over the Clustered Index Scan icon to see what is actually being carried out. You will see the following predicate being applied on the scan:

```
CONVERT(int,[testdb].[dbo].[TestTable].[MyVal],0)>(6)
AND isnumeric(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(510),
    [testdb].[dbo].[TestTable].[MyVal],0))=(1)
```

So regardless of the structure of your query, it is trying to do the CAST/CONVERT on every row in the table...

To avoid this, use a table variable or temporary table that can't be optimised out:

```
DECLARE @integers table (
    MyValInt int
)

INSERT
INTO    @integers
SELECT  CAST(MyVal AS int)
FROM    dbo.TestTable 
WHERE   ISNUMERIC(MyVal) = 1

SELECT  *
FROM    @integers
WHERE   MyValInt > 6
```

The results set you actually want to return will be different, so I'd suggest storing the primary key along with the int value in the table variable, and then doing your final query as a join like this:

```
DECLARE @integers table (
    ID int,
    MyValInt int
)

INSERT
INTO    @integers
SELECT  ID, CAST(MyVal AS int)
FROM    dbo.TestTable 
WHERE   ISNUMERIC(MyVal) = 1

SELECT  b.*
FROM    @integers t
        INNER JOIN
                TestTable b
                ON b.ID = t.ID
WHERE   t.MyValInt > 6
```

Comment: Had to go to a meeting before I could type out my response and you beat me to it :)  +1 for you

Comment: Look at Lieven answer, it seems to be a problem with nvarchar column, because he provided solution with varchar that works fine!

Answer (score 2):

> State 1, Line 67 Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '***' to data type int.

You are getting this value since some of the values in `BigMacs.BigMac` contains a non-numeric value. In your case "***".

> And when I change in first query 'select * from' to 'select top 18 * from' than I do not get error too!

It is because *at least* first returned 18 rows have numeric `BigMacs.BigMac` values.

Create a new User-Defined method called [isReallyNumeric()](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html), which addresses what is really numeric or not.

Filter out only numeric BigMac using [isReallyNumeric()](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html) function
I have also optimized the query to cast `BigMacs.BigMac` into integer once using CTE (Common Table Expression).

```
with NumericBigMacs as (
    select 
      BigMacs as BigMacsS, 
      CAST(BigMacs as Binary) as BigMacsB, 
      CAST(BigMacs as int) as BigMacsL
    from 
      McTable
    where 
      -- Filter only numeric values to compare.
      -- BigMacs Like '%[0-9]%'
      dbo.isReallyNumeric(BigMacs) = 1
)
select  *
from    NumericBigMacs NBM
where   BigMacsL > 5
```

Comment: I have still the same error. And the value of error is from row that inside select does not return at all! This is weird!

Comment: Still the same: State 1, Line 67 Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '***' to data type int.

Comment: Please reproduce bug with scripts in updated version of my question.

Comment: This script won't work because you can't guarantee that the "WHERE" clause filter will take place before the "CAST".

Comment: @David: yes, you are right.  And also, David M's answer works on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can only CAST a value to an int if it does indeed contain an int. Clearly your first 18 rows do. But then if you include more rows, it reaches a row where the value cannot be cast to an int and you get the error you describe. How about this:

```
select 
      BigMacs BigMacsS, 
      CAST(BigMacs as Binary) BigMacsB 
    from 
      McTable
    where 
      BigMacs Like '%[6-9]%'
    or
      BigMacs LIKE '%[1-9][0-5]%'
```

That will find all rows containing a number within the text of this column that is greater than 5 (assuming there are no decimals or negative numbers contained).

Comment: Sorry, missed the lines in the select. You actually want the value itself extracted as well?

Comment: And these are arbitrary strings which may or may contain an integer value embedded within them somewhere?

Comment: These strings contain numbers like 354,54364,3655 or 534 or normal text like "Can I Has Cheesburger" ec.

Comment: But not a mixture of the two? Also, how would you interpret the first one you give as an example - a list of three numbers, or a single long number?

Comment: Oh sorry, I ment 3 different numbers. And mixture? I think yes - maybe I will have somewhere text like 'Count to 5 numbers', but I do not want to get this 5 number from this string. I would like only take into account valid numbers without text.

Comment: So you only want rows that just contain numbers to be cast to ints and compared to 5?

Comment: @David M - this is what i would like to acomplish. But when I do it like I've showed it and in ways it's proposed in this topic till now, I always get this error.

Comment: In that case, you want Sung Meister's solution, which I can see nothing wrong with. Sure you can work out the teething troubles with him.

Comment: @David M - as for now solution of Sung does not work well, but hope to get solution here.

Comment: @tomaszs: Unless all the exceptional cases are addressed, this will be like chasing a goose.

Comment: Please reproduce bug with scripts in updated version of question.

Comment: @tomaszs - please see my second answer!

Answer (score 1):

OK isnumeric doesn't always work when storing character data and numbers in the same column. Nor is it limited to items which can be converted to integers. See this link for an explanation:
http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6423

My first question is why are you storing things things you want to use as numbers and characters in the same column? This is a severe design flaw and should be corrected if at all possible.

I believe the link might help you figure out what do do if you cannot change the structure.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to give the expected results

#### edit

*and* includes your where clause

```
DECLARE @McTable TABLE (BigMacs VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @McTable VALUES ('1')
INSERT INTO @McTable VALUES ('1dqsf')
INSERT INTO @McTable VALUES ('qsfsq1')
INSERT INTO @McTable VALUES ('10')

select   
  BigMacs,
  cast(BigMacs as Binary) as BigMacsB, 
  cast(BigMacs as int) as BigMacsL
from @McTable
where IsNumeric(BigMacs) = 1
      and cast(BigMacs as int) > 5
```

Comment: @tomaszs: BigMacsL is NOT a column in your actual table is it?

Comment: @Lieven - no, I choose this name so I don't have any conflicts

Comment: @tomaszs: I have changed the select. This query gives the expected result.

Comment: @Lieven - in case of your data yes. In case of my data no. And you don't have where clause on the main select query. I have this error when I add this where  Cast(table.BigMacsL as int) > 5

Comment: @tomaszs: duh, sorry about that. New try.

Comment: Please see updated post question. I've provided there scripts to reproduce my error on your server :) Hope to help communicate

Comment: @tomaszs: have you tried this latest update? It works here, even when I insert your data.

Comment: @Lieven - it's works, but you found interesting thing - when column is varchar it works, but when I change it to nvarchar (i use this) it does not work!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening: the predicate `BigMacs Like '%[0-9]%'` doesn't quite do what you think. It selects rows that have at least one digit somewhere in the string.

This is not what you want. You want strings that *only* have digits. Unfortunately, the LIKE wilcards don't give us an easy way to ask for that.

We may come close enough for your problem. If we ask for

```
not (BigMacs like "%[A-Za-z!@#$%^&*()=;:'""]%")
```

we'll filter out most rows that have anything *but* numbers. "Most", because our like wildcard doesn't contain all possible non-numeric characters. This, in turn, should allow the cast to work.

So:

```
select * from
  (
    select 
      BigMacs BigMacsS, 
      CAST(BigMacs as Binary) BigMacsB, 
      CAST(BigMacs as int) BigMacsL
    from 
      McTable
    where 
      not (BigMacs like "%[A-Za-z!@#$%^&*()=;:'""]%") 
  ) table
where 
  Cast(table.BigMacsL as int) > 5
```

Comment: you are right, it was bad use of like, but with your change the error still ocurrs!

Comment: Using isnumeric is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

I think using of [ISNUMERIC()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) function also could help.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(myval)=1 THEN myval ELSE 0 END AS INT) AS mi
    FROM dbo.TestTable 
) AS t2
WHERE mi>5
```

Comment: I have added an example how it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think that David M. has nailed it on the head, but for those who asked for a script that reproduces the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test_Int_Conversion
(
    my_id   INT IDENTITY    NOT NULL,
    my_str  VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Test_Int_Conversion PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (my_id)
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Int_Conversion (my_str) VALUES ('1')
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Int_Conversion (my_str) VALUES ('2')
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Int_Conversion (my_str) VALUES ('3')
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Int_Conversion (my_str) VALUES ('4')
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Int_Conversion (my_str) VALUES ('5')
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Int_Conversion (my_str) VALUES ('6')
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Int_Conversion (my_str) VALUES ('7')
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Int_Conversion (my_str) VALUES ('8')
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Int_Conversion (my_str) VALUES ('9')
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Int_Conversion (my_str) VALUES ('*')
GO

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
    my_id,
    CAST(my_str AS INT) my_strI
FROM
    dbo.Test_Int_Conversion
WHERE
    my_str LIKE '%[0-9]%'
) SQ
WHERE
    CAST(SQ.my_strI AS INT) > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

That code should work:

```
select
    tabela.*
from
    (
        select
                CAST(MyVal as int) MyValInt
        from
                dbo.TestTable
        where
                IsNumeric(MyVal) = 1
    ) tabela
    left join (select 1 a )a on tabela.MyValInt > 6
```

I think that the reason the original query fails may be related to the order in which the query is evaluated by SQL.